# Divide SELECT value by first entry found

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fairly inexperienced with SQL, and I have a table that looks like this (simplified version):

```
ID | Dataset | date | value
```

I'm trying to divide each value by a baseline, which would be the first entry in the database for that particular dataset.

For example, for dataset1, if the value at 05/05/2018 is 28, and the first value in the database is 4 at 01/01/2018, then I want the result to be 28/4.

thing is that not every dataset was added to the database at the same time, so they have different dates for their baseline. So if dataset1 has its first entry at 01/01/2018, dataset2 might have its first entry at 02/02/2018.

How would I go about this query? I tried a simple div, but it seems like I can only divide by a single number, and not a value-by-value table.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT DATE(date) as time, value, dataset / (
SELECT min(DATE(date)) as time, value, dataset FROM table GROUP BY dataset)
FROM table GROUP BY time, dataset
```

but I think SQL expects the denominator to be a single value in this case, not a table.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: That sub-query returns multiple rows with 3 columns. Regardless of SQL, have you ever tried to divide one number by many tupples of 3 at the same time? It should only return 1 row with 1 value.  Maybe it could use a where clause to link it with the outer query.

Comment: What version of mySQL? 8+?

Comment: Indeed, if he's using 8+ then a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) might be used for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

```
SELECT   T1.Date
        ,T1.Value/T2.Value Value
FROM TempTable T1
INNER JOIN   TempTable T2
    ON  T2.Id
        =
        (SELECT   T2.Id
         FROM     TempTable T2
         WHERE    T1.Dataset=T2.Dataset 
         ORDER BY T2.Date 
         LIMIT 1
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

"I think SQL expects the denominator to be a single value in this case, not a table."  You are on the right track, so the sub select needs to return a single value, below is an example:

```
SELECT
  value, (select value from table b where a.dataset = b.dataset and b.dt = (select min(dt) from table c where b.dataset = c.dataset))
FROM 
  table a
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you would simply do:

```
select t.*,
       t.value / first_value(t.value) over (partition by t.dataset order by t.date) as ratio
from t;
```